# Is there a native CodeIgniter function that does the reverse of $this->db->escape()?

Tags: codeigniter

I was looking for a function that does the reverse of $this->db->escape() to get the original string when it was still unescaped.

I have tried searching for it in the Codeigniter docs. I don't think I can find one.

I also tried finding a native PHP function for it( since it uses mysql_real_escape_string when using MySQL) but so far the closest thing that I can find is stripslashes()

Comment: can you give us the reasoning behind this? maybe you are just thinking about it the wrong way and we could help you get down the right path...

Comment: I agree with @Tom.  Generally, the DBMS should be doing the unescaping.

Comment: @Tom The reason behind this is that data that we are trying to insert in the database needs to be escaped. To display the data correctly, we need to unescape it

Comment: @Matthew We are using MySQL. I am not aware that there is a escaping/unescaping function native to it. I will try to find out if there is.

Comment: @arvinsim, if you use prepared statements correctly (see Query Bindings on [this page](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html)), the database software will unescape the data when it receives it.  So data will not be escaped in the database.  If it is, that means you're double-escaping.

Comment: @matthew the problem is that the data will be used as a column header in mysql. If it contains some unescaped single quotes/double quotes, the retrieval SQL will fail since we are building the SQL as a string since it can't be handled by CI's Active Record functions because of its complexity.

Comment: AN ALTERNATIVE:
Pass the data you wish to 'unescape' AND the escaped data together in array and allow for an extra unescaped field that you can use instead of 'unescaping'. If SQL is the problem, use an alternative language. I would recommend trying XML is you are not sure where to go from here. Then just connect the dots and make your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stripslashes will unescape the string correctly.

Comment: As I said, it is the only PHP function that exists that comes close to unescaping strings. I am interested in other ways to unescape strings but if I can't find one then this will have to do.